# How to return a series of dates between two columns with just one statement using Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord, generate-series, dateinterval

I have the following table:

```
create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
  ...
  t.date     "start_date",                                                  null: false
  t.time     "start_time",                                                  null: false
  t.date     "end_date",                                                    null: false
  t.time     "end_time",                                                    null: false
  ...
end
```

This table can have activities with `start_date` equals to `end_date` and other activities ending in a different date than `start_date`.

What I'm trying to do is to build a SQL query that will **return all dates** with some activity between two dates.

For example:

- `Activity 1: start_date: 2015-04-15, end_date: 2015-04-15`
- `Activity 2: start_date: 2015-04-16, end_date: 2015-04-18`

The query will receive two params: `start_date` and `end_date`, for instance:

- `start_date: 2015-04-01`
- `end_date: 2015-04-30`

And the execution will return all dates with activity between these two dates. In the example above the result would be:

- 2015-04-15
- 2015-04-16
- 2015-04-17
- 2015-04-18

The application is written using Ruby on Rails, with the database in Postgres. This could be solved using Ruby code, but I don't want do that for performance reasons.

How this query could be implemented this using only one SQL statement in Postgres? I think the `generate_series` Postgres function can help to solve this, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With :

```
INSERT INTO activities VALUES 
  ('2015-04-15', '2015-04-15'),
  ('2015-04-16', '2015-04-18'),
  ('2015-04-01', '2015-04-03')
;
```

You can use `generates_series` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day'::interval) AS date 
FROM activities
ORDER BY date;

┌────────────────────────┐
│          date          │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2015-04-01 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-02 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-03 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-15 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-16 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-17 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-18 00:00:00+02 │
└────────────────────────┘
(7 rows)
```

---

**EDIT** : Somehow forgot about the *between A and B* part.

```
  SELECT generate_series('2015-04-10','2015-04-17', '1 day'::interval) AS date -- your input values
INTERSECT 
  SELECT DISTINCT generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day'::interval) AS date
  FROM activities 
ORDER BY date ASC;

┌────────────────────────┐
│          date          │
├────────────────────────┤
│ 2015-04-15 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-16 00:00:00+02 │
│ 2015-04-17 00:00:00+02 │
└────────────────────────┘
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to supply the parameters:

```
select generate_series(p_startdate, p_enddate, '1 day'::interval)
```

If you want to get them from the data, you can do something like:

```
select generate_series(min(startdate), max(enddate), '1 day'::interval
from activities
```

I think you are looking for a combination of these:

```
select distinct s.dte
from activities a join
     generate_series(p_startdate, p_enddate, '1 day'::interval) s(dte)
     on s.dte >= a.startdate and s.dte < a.enddate;
```